# In season 17 does LoN buff work against season journey set rewards?

Tags: diablo-iii

If you get and use the class set from completing the season journey are you not wasting the seasonal LoN buff?

I'm just a casual that jumps in and out once in a while and most people seem to be recommending builds that work around 4 or 6 piece set bonuses, am I missing something or does that basically make the season buff pointless?

Comment: LoN builds are harder to get going with all the different specific pieces you need. Sets will allow you to farm and acquire the things you need in order to use a build with the LoN season buff.

Comment: I haven't looked into it much, but assuming the buff will work the same as the buff from rings, the only benefit you get from this seasonal buff is that you can use 2 extra items that will increase your damage even more with LoN buff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LoN builds are generally not that strong, but it does free you up to use 2 ancient rings to increase the benefit of the passive seasonal buff.

In your specific case, the build guides you are following are just throwing the seasonal buff out the window because the set bonuses are so crazy strong that there's no point in building around ancient items only.

To answer your question in the title of your post, yes, it does work against each other. Seasonal buffs were never thought to coincide with seasonal rewards, these two things were built separate from each other.

Comment: `LoN builds are generally not that strong` I haven't read the latest patchnotes yet, but unless every set got a huge buff, you are kinda mistaken here. Also this buff makes the achievement "GRift 45 without setparts" much easier

Comment: @XtremeBaumer You should read the latest patch notes then - blizzard buffed set bonuses by literally 30000% in certain cases.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud, I expect the damage should be equally balanced. In previous seasons we were always up for set bonuses first and then for right legendaries. Now we will be really wanting ancient legendaries instead of weak incomplete set bonuses. I am really waiting to see how lucky I'll be while leveling. And it's better to be good, because of T16 added.

Comment: @Sinatr It's not balanced in the slightest bit. All you have to do is look at the patch notes to see that it's not balanced at all. With a full set of ancient items + LoN bonus, you'll get 9750% increased damage with a full set of ancient items. The Inarius 6 piece bonus is 10000% and it's one of the worst in the game. SO not only do you have to find an useable ancient gear piece in every single slot, but your damage is lower than using this really bad set bonus.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud, don't forget what to have 6 set bonus you have 6 slots occupied with items giving you nothing (ok, much weaker or even not useful set bonus). In theory wearing ancients boosting same skill in all slots plus 9750% from season buff should be adequate (or even much better?) than set and just few item slots available to wear item boosting your skill. But yeah, ancients are rare and collecting such gear may require more effort than just getting set items from Kadala. We will see.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Your answer is completely wrong to be honest. In fact, LoN builds are the strongest ones in the game right now, even more so because of the season buff. The highest pushing builds are LoN builds for necromancer and wizard. [Rhykkers' predictions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rsdu24OOQP4) are on point for 90% of the time. Sure, some people use other builds to push just as high, but for the vast majority he is right. Also blizzard buffed only the Inarius set bonus and **no** other set at all in this season. The 30k% buff was for the Rapid Fire skill

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to FoxMcCloud, I'd say that LoN builds are way stronger than most set builds. In fact, LoN builds are the strongest push builds for this season [according to Rhykker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rsdu24OOQP4) who is right most of the times.

Not all set bonuses are "crazy strong". Some actually are that bad, that you would rather wear a few ancients than using the sets. This season, if you want to push really high in greater rifts, you mostly want to get your hands on the season journey set reward to farm ancient items effectively.

It is true that they season buff and season journey reward work against each other, but you can also use that as advantage for an easier farming for any LoN build.

The season buff is not useless if you aim for really high greater rift pushing.